# How do I properly delete a node from a linked list?

Tags: c++

I've created a linked list of animal objects. When an animal reaches its lifespan I want to remove it from the the linked list. However, whenever I run my attempt, the previous node is not being set for the second deletion of the hyena object. And the tiger object which is the following node is being deleted even though it has the highest lifespan.

Specifically in line 6 of the output, I don't understand why possum is being used as the previous node instead of chicken.

[image]

```
NodePtr temp = head;
while (temp != NULL){
    temp->data->setAge(temp->data->getAge()+1);

    if (temp->data->getAge()  > temp->data->getLifeSpan()){

        std::cout << temp->data->getAnimal() << " lifespan reached" << std::endl;
        if (temp->prev == NULL) { // remove head
            head = temp->next;
            delete(temp);
            temp = NULL;
            temp = head;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << temp->prev->data->getAnimal() << " " << temp->data->getAnimal() << " "  << temp->next->data->getAnimal() << " (prev node, curr node, next node)" << std::endl;

            NodePtr nextPtr = temp->next;
            temp = temp->prev;

            std::cout << "Current Node: " << temp->data->getAnimal() << " \tNext Node: " << nextPtr->data->getAnimal() << std::endl;


            if (temp == NULL || temp->next == NULL){
                continue;
            }

            delete(temp->next);
            temp->next = NULL;
            NodePtr prev = temp;

            temp = nextPtr;  
            continue;

        }

    }

    temp = temp->next;
}
```

Comment: Unless it's a school assignment or similar, where you have to implement your own linked list, then please don't implement your own containers. The "default" container should always be [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: You might want to look at [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

Comment: And if it's a requirement to implement your own list, then I recommend that you draw it out using pen and paper. For each operation you need to do on the list (like removing a node) draw and redraw as needed until you think you have a working algorithm, and then create code to implement that algorithm.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually, `std::list` would be linked list. `std::vector` is a dynamic array.

Comment: As a hint about removing nodes from a linked list: First find the node you want to remove; Then find the node *before* that in the list; Then make the "before" node link to the "after" node. Viola, your node is no longer in the list.

Comment: Two unrelated hints: 0) Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. The letter one is an old way and it lacks some type checking. 1) `delete` is an operator, not a function. It doesn't need parenthesis.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's what I have in the code block with the NodePtr nextPtr or at least attempted to do. I think I'm having trouble because at first its being deleted correctly, but then it gets off because the previous node being what it should be.

Comment: @NO_NAME, I think you misread something, there never was a claim that `vector` was a linked list. I had to read it twice, too. ;)

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand what this code does. I think it supposed to do a few different things at once. Extracting some operations, like removing a node, into separate functions would help.

Comment: @NO_NAME Ill give that a try, thank you. But for now sleep is calling

Comment: another hint, check pointers before dereferencing them, it doesn't pay being a believer when you are a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) useful. Here's a demo

**animal.cpp**

```
#include "animal.h"

animal::animal(std::string name, int age, int life_span) :
    name(name),
    age(age),
    life_span(life_span)
{}

bool p(const animal& obj)
{
    return (obj.getAge() > obj.getLifeSpan());
}

int main()
{
    animal cat = { std::string("cat"), 5, 10 };
    animal dog = { std::string("dog"), 20, 10 };
    std::vector<animal> vec{cat, dog};

    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](animal a) {
        std::cout << "Animal type: " << a.getName() << ", Animal age: " << a.getAge() << ", Animal lifespan: " << a.getLifeSpan() << std::endl;
        });

    vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), p), vec.end());

    std::cout << " " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Removed old animals" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " " << std::endl;

    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](animal a) {
        std::cout << "Animal type: " << a.getName() << ", Animal age: " << a.getAge() << ", Animal lifespan: " << a.getLifeSpan() << std::endl;
        });
}
```

**animal.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

class animal
{
public:
    int getAge() const  { return age; }
    int getLifeSpan() const  { return life_span; }
    std::string getName() const { return name; }
    animal(std::string name, int age, int life_span);

private:
    std::string name;
    int life_span;
    int age;
};
```

Output:

> Animal type: cat, Animal age: 5, Animal lifespan: 10 
> Animal type: dog,
>   Animal age: 20, Animal lifespan: 10
>
> Removed old animals
>
> Animal type: cat, Animal age: 5, Animal lifespan: 10

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need to do, that you need to traverse the list and update the age for each animal and then remove the nodes for animals that have died of old age -- and you really do have to write your own linked-list, then the removal isn't difficult so long as you utilize both the address of the current node (a pointer-to-pointer) and a pointer to the current node. See [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/)

When you have both the address of the current node, and a pointer to the node, you simply update what is stored at that address with the next node in the list. That removes the node from the list without having to worry about tracking the previous node. Why? Because the previous node `->next` pointer still points to that address.

Since you have a pointer to the node that was just removed from the list you simply `delete` that node and update the pointer to next node.

(**note:** the node is not actually "removed" from the list, it's place in the list is simply overwritten by the next node, effectively removing it from traversal)

Putting those pieces together, you can write your removal function as:

```
NodePtr *ptemp = &head,     /* pointer-to-pointer to head */
        temp = head;        /* pointer to head */

while (temp) {  /* traverse the list updating both ptemp and temp */
    temp->data->setAge(temp->data->getAge()+1);     /* update age */
    /* if dead */
    if (temp->data->getAge()  > temp->data->getLifeSpan()) {
        *ptemp = temp->next;    /* fill current address with next node */
        delete temp;            /* delete node that was current */
        temp = *ptemp;          /* update temp pointer to current */
    }
    else {  /* still alive */
        ptemp = &temp->next;    /* get address of next node as current */
        temp = temp->next       /* update node pointer to next */
    }
}
```

(**note:** this assumes that `NodePtr` is already a `typedef`'ed pointer to your actual struct. You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).)

The only caveat above is that a normal `delete_node` function will traverse the list until it finds a specific node that holds a given value to delete and the node is removed and traversal ends. In your case you want to traverse the entire list and check each animal's age, and remove each that has died of old-age. This requires that you not only check the age of the current node being removed, but also the node that you move into its place in the list.

What this translates into from a code standpoint is it adds an `else` clause to the function. In the case where the animal has died and you have moved the next node into its position in your list, you simply update the `temp` pointer to point to the node you have moved into the current position (`temp->next`) after the `delete` takes place. That way that node is checked for age on the next iteration.

The added `else` clause handles the normal traversal to the next node for the case where the animal at that node remains alive.

This code hasn't been compiled/tested (because there was no [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work with), but should work as advertised. Give it a go and let me know if you have any problems and I'm happy to help further. (add the MCVE if I need to help further)